# Erro ao usar MapPath 'http:/..is not a valid virtual path.'

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Estou tentando abrir um aquivo no page_load através de uma função **RetornaCaminho()** que retorna a URL do arquivo.

```
reEditorContrato.Open(MapPath(RetornaCaminho(CodigoArquivo)))
```

*obs: reEditorContrato é um controle ASPxRichEdit da DevExpress*

A função me retorna  a string "http://localhost:51696/exemplo/contratos/Contrato.docx", mas no momento que ele vai abrir pelo MapPath ele me retorna um erro.

'http:/localhost:51696/exemplo/contratos/Contrato.docx' is not a valid virtual path.

Percebi que nessa parte http:/ ele retira uma barra e creio eu que é por esse motivo que o caminho da sempre inválido.

Alguma solução?

Comment: O erro deve estar em usar `MapPath`, retire ele. Deixe assim: `reEditorContrato.Open(RetornaCaminho(CodigoArquivo))`.

Comment: Já tentei dessa maneira, o método open não suporta esse tipo de formato "http...".

Answer (score 0):

Bom, como pode ver [neste link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx), o método MapPath só aceita caminhos físicos do servidor *(o tal do virtual path na mensagem de erro)*. Neste caso, creio que você teria que passar seu caminho desta forma para a função: ***"/exemplo/contratos/Contrato.docx"***, ou seja, sem a parte do ***"http://..."***, isso explicaria o tratamento que ele faz removendo uma das barras do ***"http://"***.

Espero ter ajudado.

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição!